# The tag [feasibility] and its lack of proper documentation

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [feasibility](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feasibility) is only used in two questions, has no wiki, and the questions are both tagged [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)[javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)[feasibility](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feasibility).

These questions are asked by 2 different users. Here they are:

- [JSF**k with only 5 symbols?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75423/jsfk-with-only-5-symbols)
- ["Could you repeat yourself?" aka Could a doubled character solution exist in JavaScript?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94811/could-you-repeat-yourself-aka-could-a-doubled-character-solution-exist-in-jav)

There are two options this question covers:

- Burninate or synonimize with [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips), because the tag is not useful at all.
- Make tag wiki, because this tag has a use, but it is not well-documented.

If not the first, the second option should apply, because *what is this tag for?*

**EDIT**: The tag seems to have been burninated.

Comment: AKA "The feasibility of [feasibility]".

Comment: @DJMcMayhem When I made this question, I was about to shut my PC off, so there was no time for improving.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer There was no need to post answers at all in the first place. If you don't have time to make a proper answer, then simply don't. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Geobits No, nothing like that at all. It should be "The usefulness of [feasibility]". But, your suggestion is at the very least humorous enough.

Comment: @MartinEnder These are kind of "draft answers", i.e. answers that belong to me but are not fully complete yet. I know I should have added some detail like "Draft answer, please bear with it." Or, just let others post their own arguings? Edit: Added more detail to everything now. But, I just got on my PC, so it might still not be perfect.